# What is the moment of inertia of liquid bodies?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Consider a liquid body in outer space. Is the moment of inertia a constant or does it vary when you try to make it spin? After all the form changes when spinning and due to viscosity the inner parts of the body have a "retarded" rotation.

Comment: Worth a read? https://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.101.234501

Comment: In my judgment, moment of inertia is not a very useful concept for fluids.

Comment: Fluid and gymnast are non-rigid bodies.  Gymnasts do complicated movements.  Liquid itself has internal and surface movements.

Answer (score 1):

The moment of inertia of a body is calculated as follows:

$$I = \int dI = \int r^2dm$$

where

$I =$ moment of inertia

$m$ = mass

$r$ = distance of the mass from the axis of rotation

As you can see, the moment of inertia is a function of the mass and the distance of the mass from the axis of rotation. A liquid or any fluid in general, when rotated, will feel an outward force (if you are seeing from a frame of reference such as the moon) which will try to change the volume of the liquid body. There are forces which act against this change but ultimately there will be some change in the configuration. Therefore, as the positions of the point masses change, the moment of inertia will change as well.